# Why memleak with new operator in constructor's initialization list?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, constructor, new-operator, valgrind

Given a simple class in C++ with a private member variable `name` and a basic constructor:

```
#include <QString>

class Testclass
{
  private:
    QString *name;

  public:
    Testclass(): name(new QString()) {}
};
```

Why does valgrind's memcheck complains about 8 bytes in 1 block, which are definitely lost when using this constructor?

Comment: What's the point on dynamically allocating `name`?

Comment: Is the leak at the point where you create the object, or later when you reassign the pointer (possibly without `delete`-ing the first pointer)?

Comment: You should treat any `new` in your as a big, flashing warning sign and consider it an *error* until you have proven that it is in fact correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
~Testclass(){delete name;}
```

Will plug your leak. C++ doesn't (and shouldn't) do this for you.

ETA: ildjarn correctly points out that you should also have a copy constructor and assignment operator.

```
TestClass(const TestClass &cp): name(new QString(*(cp.name)) ) {}
const TestClass& operator=(const Testclass&rhs)
{
  (*name)=(*hrs.name);
  return *this;
}
```

Otherwise, the default copy constructor or assignment operator will cause the same memory to be deleted twice. Most classes that require a destructor should replace or disable the default copy constructor and assignment operator. This is called the "Rule of Three."

You might want to consider simply holding the QString by value, because it's likely itself a lightweight container class, like std::string or std::vector. But if you're a C++ beginner, doing it this way once is a valuable lesson.

Comment: Of course, he also needs a copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator in addition to a destructor. [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))